# Why Wait or why to wait

Tags: infinitive-clauses, bare-infinitives

Which is correct

- Why wait until tomorrow.
- Why *to* wait until tomorrow

Comment: As a reminder, your question must contain adequate context for it to be answerable. What is the whole idea you are trying to express? What do you think is the difference, if any, between the two examples, and why? Have you found other examples of similar constructions on the web or in print? Without this kind of background information, we can only speculate as to what your actual question is, which is likely to get this question closed. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] if you have not done so.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, none of them is correct. They are questions ended in a full-stop (instead of question marks).

However, matching your intention, the following is idiomatic:

> Why wait until tomorrow?

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is "Why wait until tomorrow". Since you have "until" in the sentence you don't need to put "to" there. You could say "Why would you wait until tomorrow?" or "Why is he waiting until tomorrow?" But not "Why to wait until tomorrow?".

Hope this helps.